# In a userscript/greasemonkey, how do you use a newer version of jQuery when the website already uses an older version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to write a userscript for a website that is already using an ancient version of jQuery. If I `@require` a modern version in the userscript, I get a console error about how a field named `exists` doesn't exist. Since these two versions of jQuery are incompatible, is there any way to use them both without them conflicting?

Comment: I'd rather evaluate if you need jquery at all nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's an even better solution than this, but here's what I've come up with: `@require` jQuery the way you'd normally want, then at the end of your script, put a [$.noConflict();](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). As some of your userscript functions may need to use the latest version, it may not be enough to put [$.noConflict();](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) as the last line. To avoid thinking about that possibility, you can write your script like this:

```js
...
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

((jQueryAsAParameter) => {
  // use jQueryAsAParameter in here, because $ may refer to the old version
  ...
})($);

$.noConflict();
```

This is called an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) if you want to learn more. The above is kind of weird. I wrote it that way to make the next example easier to understand. This achieves the same effect, but in my opinion, it's more idiomatic.

```js
...
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(($) => {
  ...
})($);

$.noConflict();
```